# Using OpenCV4Android, how do I dismiss the Value component of an HSV image, so that algorithms become less sensitive to light conditions?

Tags: opencv, hsv, android

In this beginner's tutorial on OpenCV4Android, it is written,

> The HSV and HLS decompose colors into their hue, saturation and
>   value/luminance components, which is a more natural way for us to
>   describe colors. **You might, for example, dismiss the value
>   component, making your algorithm less sensitive to the light
>   conditions of the input image.**

The question is that how can I do that? For example in this [sample application](https://github.com/nehiljain/opencv4android/tree/master/samples/color-blob-detection) (say in the `onTouch()` method of [this class](https://github.com/nehiljain/opencv4android/blob/master/samples/color-blob-detection/src/org/opencv/samples/colorblobdetect/ColorBlobDetectionActivity.java) where `touchedRegionHsv` is calculated on Line#138), how can I remove/dismiss the `Value` component of the HSV, so that the algorithms become less sensitive to the light conditions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, as I can see you are only adding the 3 channel and dividing them by the number of pixels, maybe you can remove this channel by using:

```
for(int i=0; i<touchedRegionHsv.height; i++){
    for(int j=0; j<touchedRegionHsv.width; j++){
        cv.SetReal3D(touchedRegionHsv, i, j, 2, 0)
    }
}
```

Hope this can be useful to you, cheers!